# API Gateway stages gives me "Not Found" message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

in API Gateway, I created stages and they don't work.
Just giving me `{"message":"Not Found"}`.

`https://<API ID>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/` works.
`https://<API ID>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/<stagename>` doesn't work.

I've searched some similar issues for a few days and they couldn't give me answer I want :(
Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

1. Enable Automatic Deployment option doesn't work
2. Disalbe Automatic Deployment option and deploy doesn't work